# Extract substring enclosed by HTML tags Coldfusion

Tags: string, coldfusion, substring, extract

I have maybe a silly question. Let's say that we have a string:

```
"my name <em>is</em> Tom <em>Papas</em> and I am 30 <em>years</em> of age<em>!</em>"
```

The question is: how do we extract the substrings that are enclosed within the `<em>` tags and output them as a list, array or a comma delimited string using coldfusion? Notice that we don't know what substrings are enclosed within the tags. We need to extract substrings blindly.

Thank you in advance,

Tom

Greece

Comment: **Use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org)** - if you get stuck, search for details (e.g. Ben Nadel has blogged it before), and if after that you're still stuck come back with information on what you've tried and what your problem is.

Comment: @PeterBoughton I think you should post it as an answer. :)

Comment: Dunno. It's more of a pointer than an answer? I don't have time to write a detailed explanation for using jSoup with CF, but if anyone else wants to they're very welcome to do so. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/download) and put the jar in your CF's lib folder

```
html = "my name <em>is</em> Tom <em>Papas</em> and I am 30 <em>years</em> of age<em>!</em>";

dom = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup").parse(html);
emElements = dom.getElementsByTag("em");

results = [];
for (em in emElements)
    arrayAppend(results, em.text());
```

For more info: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-Parsing-Traversing-And-Mutating-HTML-With-ColdFusion-And-jSoup.htm

Or use basic Regex

```
matches = rematch("<em>[^<]*</em>", html);
results = [];
for (match in matches)
    arrayAppend(results, rereplace(match, "<em>(.*)</em>", "\1") );
```

Comment: Many tahnks my friend. i have one more question. I have noticed that using tag syntax it work in contrary using script syntax (concerning jsoup example). Maybe it is my poor progarming skills. Notice that i am using openBD as CFML Server. At the following two comments follows the code block that i tryied on openBD:

Comment: Tag syntax(working):  `<cfset html = "my name <em>is</em> Tom <em>Papas</em> and I am 30 <em>years</em> of age<em>!</em>">
<cfset dom = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup").parse(html)>
<cfset emElements = dom.getElementsByTag("em")>
<cfset results = ArrayNew(1)>

<cfloop array="#emElements#" index="em">
       <cfset arrayAppend(results, em.text() )>
</cfloop>

<cfset myList = ArrayToList(results, ",")>

<cfoutput>
    The list(tag-coded): #myList#
</cfoutput>`

Comment: Script syntax(not working):  `<cfscript>
html = "my name <em>is</em> Tom <em>Papas</em> and I am 30 <em>years</em> of age<em>!</em>";

dom = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup").parse(html);
emElements = dom.getElementsByTag("em");
results = [];
for (em in emElements)
    arrayAppend(results, em.text());
 Writeoutput("The list(script-coded): " & (ArrayToList(results, ",")));
</cfscript>


<!---<cfset myList = ArrayToList(results, ",")>
<cfoutput>
 The list(script-coded): #myList#
</cfoutput>--->`

Comment: Thank you for you reply! What i mean is that openBSD server can consume the tag syntax CFML code block rather than script syntax. I don't know why. The funny thing is that the regex example that you provided works flawlessly both script and tag syntaxed. The error that BD server returned is something like: "The page you were executing caused an internal server error" and `java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.naryx.tagfusion.cfm.engine.cfArrayData.getData(Unknown Source)
at com.naryx.tagfusion.cfm.parser.script.CFForInStatement.Exec(Unknown Source)at com.naryx.tagfusion.........`

Comment: You mean OpenBD?  It could be choking at the `for-in` syntax and not supporting  `Iterable` correctly.  See: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html You can iterate yourself, or call `toArray()` and loop through the array.

Answer (score 0):

In CF 10 or Railo 4, you can combine xmlParse() with [Underscore.cfc](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/)'s map() function, like so:

```
str = "my name <em>is</em> Tom <em>Papas</em> and I am 30 <em>years</em> of age<em>!</em>";
str = "<myWrapper>" & str & "</myWrapper>";
xmlObj = XmlParse(str);
resultAsArray = _.map(xmlObj.myWrapper.xmlChildren, function (val) {
    return val.xmlText;
});
```

(Disclaimer: I wrote  Underscore.cfc)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Underscore.cfc is a real contribution! Unfortunately i am using openBD CFML server, but that isn't the point. Underscore rocks! Well done again!

Comment: Hey thanks! I really appreciate the feedback. FYI, I wanted to make Underscore work on OpenBD, but they don't have any plans to support anonymous functions, which kills that idea :(